# Поиск текста в строке

Tags: java

Есть переменная (String), которая содержит некоторый текст, в любой части которого может быть номер телефона в формате +nnnnnnnnnnnn. Всего 12 цифр и знак "+" в начале. Каким образом выделить эти 12 цифр (либо строку, содержащую 12 цифр и "+" в начале) в отдельную переменную?

Comment: Используй регулярные выражения, похожий вопрос с ответом тут - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4662265/2082873

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 String s = "rgrg r +123456789876efgr";
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\+[0-9]{12}");
 Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
 while (m.find()){
     System.out.println(m.group()); // m.group твоя переменная
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку сразу известно то, что все номера телефонов будут начинаться на `"+375"` и что цифр будет `12` - нашел альтернативный метод:

```
String i1 = "yfhiyy yrgkytff +375338550935 hyffhjju";

//Проверка на наличие номера телефона в тексте
boolean isContain = i1.contains("+375");
if (isContain) {
   //Вычисляем позицию знака "+" в строке
   int ant = i1.indexOf("+");
   //Выводим 12 символов сразу после знака "+"
   String telefon = i1.substring(ant, ant+13);
   System.out.println("Номер телефона: " + telefon);
} else { 
   System.out.println("Номер телефона в строке не найден");
}
```

Comment: Используй регулярные выражения для таких задач, т.к. это быстрее и читабельнее

Comment: Благодарю за информацию!